# why cannot I edit admin permissions for the permission page in D8?

Tags: 8, users

All permission boxes for administrators are disabled "greyed out". [image]

I can do it via drush but not through the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because administrator is an admin role, that means it has all the permissions all the time. Editing it via drush won't do anything.

If you want a role not have all permissions it must not be an admin role, but that means you need to manually add new permissions.

Comment: But in my use case the permission is "can login via QR code" which I NOT want for administrator roles...